# Formula Excel to Display Data When the Third Character J

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to display data when the third character = J
Example :

```
Jajar
asjur
bajar
kaka
dede
lala
```

Result

```
jajar
asjur
bajar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`MID`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028).

```
=MID(A1,3,1) = "j"
```

It will evaluate to `TRUE` if the 3rd character is `j`. Otherwise, it will evaluate to `FALSE`.

[image: output]

If you want to get the contents of `A` instead of TRUE/FALSE, combine it with [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2). i.e.

```
=IF(MID(A1,3,1) = "j", A1, "")
```

[image: output2]

Comment: When Data = true how I can to display the data

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula in the conditional formatting:

```
=FIND("j",A1)=3
```

It will evaluate to `TRUE`, if it is `TRUE`.
If it is `FALSE`, simply make sure that the font becomes white.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula as array formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(MID($A$1:$A$6,3,1)="j",ROW($A$1:$A$6),""),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

***Screenshot***
[image]

You have to adjust formula based on your data position in worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<3,"",IF(UPPER(MID(A2,3,1))="J","X",""))
```

and copy down.  Then AutoFilter column **B**:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the `UPPER()`? In my Excel, `="j"="J"` returns `TRUE`.